# Suppose $\mathcal{E}$ is a globally generated algebraic vector bundle on a scheme, then are there bounds on the number of generators needed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The title more or less speaks for itself. The reason I ask this question is because there is a theorem of [Forster](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01112211) that says: if $\mathcal{E}$ is a vector bundle of rank $n$ over a noetherian **affine** scheme of dimension $d$, then it is globally generated by at most $n+d$ sections. It is "Satz 2" in the link.

I am curious about an analogue of this result for vector bundles on schemes. More precisely, I hope an appropriate variant holds: Let $X$ be a noetherian quasicompact scheme of dimension $d$ and $\mathcal{E}$ a globally generated locally free sheaf of rank $n$ on $X$. Then $\mathcal{E}$ is generated by at most $n+d$ sections.

Edit: There seems to be some stuff on this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.09426v4.pdf) by Uriya First (Abstract and Section 7 in the preprint).

Comment: Suppose that $X$ is a projective variety with a very ample line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$. Then, $\mathcal{E}(m)$ is globally generated for $m\gg 0$. Your assumption would then imply that the function $p(m)$ is bounded. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: @AlexYoucis What is $p(m)$ in this case? The Hilbert polynomial?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry -- I should have said $p(m):=\dim H^0(\mathcal{E}(m))$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis All good. And no I do not think that my assumption would imply $p(m)$ is bounded. I'm asking if I can pick $n+d$ sections to generate everything so that gives a surjection $O_X^{n+d}\to>\mathcal{E}(m)$ but it need not necessarily give a surjection of $H^0$'s. Am I wrong?

Comment: Nope -- I just misread the question. I apologize for the confusion!

Comment: What you say is correct and Forster's proof can be adapted.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, Forster's proof can indeed be adapted. It turns out a variant and proof can  be found in Theorem 7.7. of the [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.09426v4.pdf) by Uriya First. I have quoted it below.

> Theorem 7.7. Let $k$ be an infinite field, let $d \in \mathbb{N} \cup\{0\}$, let $X$ be a finite type $k$-scheme, and let $V$ be a rank-n vector bundle over $X$. If $V$ is generated by global sections, then there is an open subscheme $U$ of $X$ such that $\operatorname{codim}(X-U, X)>d$ and $\left.V\right|_U$ is generated by $n+d$ global sections. In particular, if $\operatorname{dim} X=d$, then $V$ is generated by $n+d$ global sections.

Comment: If $X:=Spec(A)$ is an affine scheme and if $E$ is a finite rank projective $A$-module with associated locally free sheaf $\mathcal{E}$, there are results on bounds on the number $d_E$ of generators of $E$ as $A$-module (see Matsumuras book). If $e_1,..,e_n$ generate $E$ as $A$-module you get a set of global sections generating $\mathcal{E}$. This result does not assume you are over a field.